# Other world ruled by evil sorcerer

Tags: story-identification, books

I search a book I read a long time ago (approximately 2011).

It is a fantasy book series about an other world that is connected with our world through little wooden portals (small enough to fit into a bag, but somehow people got easily through). In the other world there is no modern day technology, but a lot of magic and plenty different intelligent species. In the other world time passes a lot faster, so a week there was something like a day in our world.

A boy who lost his parents gets to the other world and meets companions, notably a little slime who has so powerful telepathic abilities that he is actually one of strongest creatures of this strange other world. An evil very powerful sorcerer tries to seize control of the other world, the boy and his companies embark on a journey to stop him.

Some info I remember:

- The boy plays basketball (also one match against creatures of the other world).
- Once someone already tried to kill the sorcerer, but failed. The sorcerer made the attacker invincible and put him in a pot of acid to torment him for all eternity.
- Pretty sure the boy is an orphan.
- Pretty sure the name of the other world is the title of the book/series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year was "a long time ago?"  Do you remember the cover art of the book(s)?

Comment: @DavidW it was before 2011, when I was still a little child. I remember seeing the series in the bookshelves of a library. Sadly I don't remember anything about the cover :/.
I borrowed at least the first two books and read them.
Thanks for the quick response!